# Using prior date search in OpenQuery Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to run an openquery with a where parameter of yesterdays date but getting an error.. can anyone help

```
select top 10 * into #temp1 
from openquery(mysql1, 'select * from test.T1 where source = "Data" and 
  calcdate = SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 102), '.', '-') ')
```

Thanks

here is the Error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Show your error. And I guess you are using MS SQL Server, retag your question so is more accurately tagged.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing escaped quotes and `SELECT` in `WHERE clause` is redundant.

Try this:

```
select top 10 * into #temp1 
from openquery(mysql1, 'select * from test.T1 where source = ''Data'' and 
  calcdate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), ''%Y-%m-%d'')')
```

Comment: OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mysql1" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.45-community-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 102), ".", "-")' at line 2".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mysql1".

Comment: @Greg You haven't in your tags `mysql` and i missed the fact that your linked server is `MySQL`. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT statement must be in brackets or use without SELECT keyword

```
select top 10 * into #temp1 
from openquery(mysql1, 'select * from test.T1 where source = "Data" and 
  calcdate = (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 102), '.', '-')) ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another select query to use convert functions. Also *`to get the correct results`* you should be *`comparing dates not varchar values`* in the *`where clause`*. If `calcdate` isn't a date type field then convert it before comparison. Try this;

```
Select top 10 * into #temp1 
From openquery(mysql1, 'Select * from test.T1 where source = ''Data'' and 
  calcdate =  dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())')
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9662) of your select query string